# Pass bidimensional array to c# model

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I am passing a array from javascript to server that looks something like this:

```
tableGrid: 
[
   [
      ["row0cell0", "row0cell1", "row0cell2", "row0cell3", "row0cell4"],
      ["row1cell0", "row1cell1", "row1cell2", "row1cell3", "row1cell4"]
   ]
]
```

I need to pass it to C# Web API, so at the moment I want to add it to a existing model that I created for the table, so i put this on my model:

```
public List<Array> tableGrid { get; set; }
```

I want to access the elements as I do with a multimensional array like arr[2][2], any tip guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a list of list of string like:

```
public List<List<string>> tableGrid { get; set; }
```

put that in a class myClass and add it to [FromBody] in your controller.

```
public PostData([FromBody] myClass) {

}
```

Then you should send it via POST from JavaScript.